# Unable to set title for rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I've been on a personal project learning ruby with rails, and things have gone pretty well. I've started to transition to polish and deployment, and configuring titles for which part of the website you're in. I tried the accepted solution over at: http://tinyurl.com/jzqmuw2, but my title still defaults to my project name which isn't clean. I've looked at a few other solutions, and some of them are okay, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

I'm using JRuby 9.0.4.0 (2.2.2) with openjdk 8 on a an ec2 micro t2 while I test.

The relevant code:

${root}/homepage/index.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>
    <%- title "BleuEngine" %>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>BleuEngine</h1>
  <p>Website for BleuEngine</p>
</body>
```

${root}/app/helper/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Setting titles for each page
  def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
end
```

${root}/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for?(:title) : "BleuEngine" %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Layouts.html was actually application.html.erb. fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ${root}/homepage/index.html.erb view to:

```
<%- title "Whatever title you want to appear on this page" %>

<h1>BleuEngine</h1>
<p>Website for BleuEngine</p>
```

You don't need the `<head>` stuff in your view, because that should be in your layout file. Also, you don't need `<body>` tags, since your view is inserted between body tags in the `<%= yield %>` line in your layout file.

Finally, add the title line to the Head section of your layout file ${root}/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb to render the Title.

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "BleuEngine" %></title>
```

Comment: It actually is application.html.erb, I mistyped it.

Comment: Thanks for the standard practice, you're right where the head should be, I just made a small one-off rails app to test this bit. I see what I did, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`content_for?(:title)` returns a Boolean saying if you have content or not.
It doesn't return the actual content. `yield(:title)` does that.

Change

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? content_for?(:title) : "BleuEngine" %></title>
```

to

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "BleuEngine" %></title>
```

Comment: This fixed it, and I see what I did. Thanks!